# Disable Bash's programmable autocompletion (based on command)

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Bash in my Fedora 16 seems to autocomplete arguments based on the command itself. So if I for example type

> `cd` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

… it will only show directories.

There are however far too many commands where it doesn't know the expected input types, so is there any way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `bash-completion` package.

Comment: You will need to restart any running instances of bash for the change to take effect.  Also consider using `sudo apt-get --purge remove bash-completion` as suggested below.  This appears to remove a file from `/etc` referencing a completion-related file that bash will otherwise complain about.

Comment: This is what I like to do because I hate the package, but raines's answer is the right one for the question as asked and useful on boxes you can't remove stuff on (because others users want it)

Answer (score 24):

```
shopt -u progcomp
```

will disable program based completion and TAB will do regular file/dir completion again.  You can do this on a shell by shell basis (or put in in .bashrc for all shell in your account) rather than remove the bash-completion package for everyone. Running `complete -r` removes all program completion settings so there are none defined.  This means if you want to turn it on again you have to redefine them all again.  Whereas if you used `shopt -u progcomp` to turn it off, you can just run `shopt -s progcomp` to turn it back on again.

Comment: Sounds great, and actually **disables** it (like the Q asked) instead of removing it entirely. Could put in `.bashrc` too. Should be the correct answer IMO

Answer (score 8):

Another way to disable it on a per-user basis is by doing `complete -r` in your `.bashrc` file. Type `help complete` for more information.

Comment: This is a very good option to take when one doesn't have superuser privileges (e.g., using a computer at a university).

Answer (score 1):

Just removing the package is not enough, you also want to purge the files:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove bash-completion`